# RxJava: calling unsubscribe from within onNext

Tags: java, rx-java

I wonder whether it is legal to call `unsubscribe` from within `onNext` handler like that:

```
List<Integer> gatheredItems = new ArrayList<>();

Subscriber<Integer> subscriber = new Subscriber<Integer>() {
    public void onNext(Integer item) {
        gatheredItems.add(item);
        if (item == 3) {
            unsubscribe();
        }
    }
    public void onCompleted() {
        // noop
    }
    public void onError(Throwable sourceError) {
        // noop
    }
};

Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(0,100);

source.subscribe(subscriber);
sleep(1000);
System.out.println(gatheredItems);
```

The above code correctly outputs that just four elements were gathered: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. But if somebody changes the source observable to be cached:

```
Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(0,100).cache();
```

Then all hundred elements are gathered. I don't have a control over source observable (whether it is cached or not), so how to definitely unsubscribe from within `onNext`?

BTW: So is unsubscribing within `onNext` wrong thing to do?

(My actual use case is that in `onNext` I'm actually writing to output stream, and when an `IOException` occurs nothing more could be written to the output so I need to somehow stop further processing.)

Answer (score 3):

The cache() caches everything once the first subscriber arrives and it doesn't give any options to stop it from downstream. You need to stop the stream before the cache() to avoid too much retention:

```
Observable<Integer> source = Observable.range(1, 100);

PublishSubject<Integer> stop = PublishSubject.create();

source
.doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Generating " + v))
.takeUntil(stop)
.cache()
.doOnNext(new Action1<Integer>() {
    int calls;
    @Override
    public void call(Integer t) {
        System.out.println("Saving " + t);
        if (++calls == 3) {
            stop.onNext(1);
        }
    }
})
.subscribe();
```

Edit: the example above doesn't work below 1.0.13 so here is a version which should:

```
SerialSubscription ssub = new SerialSubscription();

ConnectableObservable<Integer> co = source
        .doOnNext(v -> System.out.println("Generating " + v))
        .replay();

co.doOnNext(v -> {
    System.out.println("Saving " + v);
    if (v == 3) {
        ssub.unsubscribe();
    }
})
.subscribe();

co.connect(v -> ssub.set(v));
```

Comment: This code doesn't work as expected, it prints hundred times "Generating" followed by hundred times "Saving". I would excpect "Saving" only four times.

Comment: I run my example before I posted it so it prints 3 lines each. Did you try it verbatim or you tried inserting it into your flow?

Comment: I used your example verbatim, just added main and imports. I had run it on javarx 1.0.12 on two different computers, and it always prints "Saving" hundred times.